# How to prepend zeros to text until certain length

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that looks like this '12345' and another column that tells this number's length.
I need to add leading zeros to it until length in another column. Values in length column are either 8 or 6. If number in this column is less than 6 or 8 then add zeros until it becomes that length. I tried this but this isn't working:

```
=TEXT(H2,"0000000")
```

Data:
[image]

Edit: output

"033328" or "00009971"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following - SUBSTITUTE to replace the quotes, TEXT to add leading zeros, and then RIGHT to size to the appropriate length:

```
=RIGHT(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(H2,"""",""),"00000000"),I2)
```

[image]

If you need the quotes in the output, then use the following:

```
=""""&RIGHT(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(H2,"""",""),"00000000"),I2)&""""
```

[image]

Comment: This is the output 3328''

Comment: Do you mean you need quotes in the output?

Comment: Here:   ''33328''

Comment: As you can see in my screenshot, that's not what I get.

Comment: Yes. columns are needed in output. But in this case I copied your code as it is and this is output it gave

Comment: Can you edit your question with what the output should be?

Comment: It isn't giving me just the number that is shown in your output

Comment: The only problem was that in substitute I replace """ with "'". Double quote with a single quote. and it works just fine

Comment: But need the inverted commas now

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=REPLACE(A2,2,0,REPT("0",B2-LEN(A2)+2))
```

Comment: Short and sweet. I figured the substituting and re-adding quotes was cumbersome... but didn't have much appetite to work on simplifying. This is much better.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to just treat the number column as text, you could do:

```
=CONCATENATE(REPT("0",I2-LEN(H2)),H2)
```

Oh, I see the quotes are part of your input text... To discard those (hardwired, or you could do the replace thing):

```
=CONCATENATE(REPT("0",I5+2-LEN(H5)),MID(H5,2,LEN(H5)-2))
```

If you did want to do the replace I would probably add a hidden column that holds the unquoted text, and probably another that holds the length of that text in order to avoid the repetition in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Close to your approach

```
=""""&TEXT(MID(H2,2,LEN(H2)-2),REPT("0",I2))&""""
```